# trying to count down from a number, not working

Tags: python, for-loop, count

```
def countdownList(l):  # 3. prints number of files left to process
    count = len(l)
    count = count - 1
    print count, " files left to go."
    if count == 0:
        print "Finished!"
```

This function, when placed in a for loop is supposed to count down from the number of files being processed to zero.  It is not recognizing the line `count = count - 1` so if there are 41 files, it prints `41 files left to go` 41 times.

Comment: Well unless the list is changing size, this is always going to print the original length of the list...

Comment: would you show the code for using this function?

Comment: What is in l? Are you removing filenames from l , when one file is processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace below code line and place it outside function:

```
count = len(l)
```

as:

```
count = len(l)
def countdownList(l):  # 3. prints number of files left to process
    global count
    count = count - 1
    print count, " files left to go."
    if count == 0:
        print "Finished!"
```

Comment: Then I get this... `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 0):

`count = len(l)` keeps resetting `count` to `41` each time through the loop when you call the function. You need to loop inside the function or remove the element from l each call.

```
l = [1,2,3]

for x in l:
    process(x)
    countdownList(l)
    l.pop(0) # shorten list by 1 each iteration
```

Or simply use enumerate:

```
l = [1,2,3]

for ind, x in enumerate(l):
    print len(l) - ind, " files left to go." 
    process(x)
```

Comment: I tried that, but then it prints the countdown from 41 to zero 41 times.

Comment: then you are doing the same thing 41 times, try using enumerate